# Building reports with visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, reporting-services, crystal-reports

Im building a new system  and one of the requirements is for it to be able to send out reports, print checks (I know its not a report but it will be completed as if it was a report.), etc. I have background using SSRS and crystal reports but i want to get other developers opinion on the better of the 2 as well as what other report builders I should consider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had a lot of success with SSRS. It works well for reports that you want to print out (paginated, pixel-perfect, etc.). It also has great scheduling functionality. It seems to have more flexibility than Crystal in terms of dynamically setting property values with expressions. At my last job we converted all the Crystal reports to SSRS and it worked out well.